# How to deal with relationship between Entities that can have an unknown amount of variables?

Tags: android, database, entity, android-room, entity-relationship

I'm facing a little problem in the development of my app. Basically the user should be able to set "rules" in the app, as in "If this *Condition* then do this *Reaction*". I then want to save this rule in the Roomdatabase I'm using.

That in itself isn't hard, the problem is that it can also be multiple conditions that are associated with AND or OR, as in "If this *Condition* AND this *Condition* then do this *Reaction*". And the same can be applied for the reactions. Since I don't know how many Conditions or Reactions the user is gonna input, I'm having a hard time figuring out how the Entities in RoomDatabase should look like and what type of relationship should be between them.

If anyone could help me with this, it'd be really appreciated !

Comment: You can save all rules and reactions in Single column in some particular format probably Json and then use a type Converter  . If this does not work in your case the you need provide some more details .

Comment: I did think of simply even saving it in a String as it would also be possible but wouldn't that go against the 3.NF?

Comment: I don't think so .